# TypeError: You may only yield a function, promise, generator... when yielding app.listen()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, generator

I cannot tell what is wrong with this generator function:

```
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/voyanta';
var db;
var server;

co(function*() {
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    db = yield MongoClient.connect(dbUrl);
    server = yield app.listen(3000);
    console.log('Connected to database. Listening on port 3000.');

}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```

It looks perfectly fine to me, but the line "server = yield app.listen(3000);" creates the error: "Type Error: You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following object was passed: "[object Object]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.listen(3000)` doesn't return a promise.

Instead of:

```
server = yield app.listen(3000);
```

you can do something like:

```
server = app.listen(3000);
yield new Promise(res => server.on('listening', res));
```

or better yet:

```
server = app.listen(3000);
yield new Promise((res, rej) => {
    server.on('listening', res);
    server.on('error', rej);
});
```

Tested with this example:

```
var co = require('co');
var app = require('express')();

co(function*() {
    server = app.listen(3000);
    yield new Promise((res, rej) => {
        server.on('listening', res);
        server.on('error', rej);
    });
    console.log('Listening on port 3000.');
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```